# Proof with Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $u$ = ($u$1, $u$2, $u$3) ∈ $\Bbb R^3$
and $v$ = ($v$1, $v$2) ∈ $\Bbb R^2$ be non-zero (row)vectors.

Define F : $\Bbb R^3$ → $\Bbb R^2$ by F($x$) = ($u$ · $x$)$v$.

(a) Show that ker F = ${({span\ \ {u}})}^⊥$.

(b) Show that $R$(F) = span($v$).

(c) Show that the standard matrix of F is $v^{t}u$.

Here, F is a linear transformation, ker(F) and $R$(F) is the Kernel and Range  of the linear transformation respectively. The $(span\ \ {u})^{⊥}$ is the set of all vectors orthogonal to the span of $u$ and $v^t$ is the transpose of the row vector $v$

With part a) I figured that if ($u$ · $x$)$v$ belonged to the ker(F), then ($u$ · $x$)$v$=$0$ which meant that $u$ · $x$=$0$ because it previously stated that both $u$ and $v$ are non-zero vectors. From here I'm not actually sure how to show that the ker(F)=$(span\ \ \{u\})^{⊥}$ unless it has something to do with the dot product of the vectors $x$ and $u$ that I 'm missing.

The other parts, I'm unsure if I must first do part a) in order to complete them. Does anyone have any advice or directions from here. Please feel free to edit my question for extra clarity. 
Thank You!

Comment: How do you define $\text{span}(u)^{\perp}$? Once you write that down, you can see that $\text{span}(u)^{\perp} = \{u\}^{\perp}$, which is precisely the condition you have.

Answer (score 0):

(a) The kernel of $F$ is the set of all $x$ such that $F(x) = 0$. Because $v$ is arbitrary, we must have $(u \cdot x) = 0$. Hence, $\ker F$ is the set of all vectors $x$ that are orthogonal to $u$. Now if $x$ is orthogonal to $u$, then $x$ is also orthogonal to the span of $u$, which is simply all scalar multiples of $u$. Thus $\ker F = (\operatorname{span} u)^\perp$.

(b) The span of $v$ is all scalar multiples $a$ of $v$. We can choose $x$ such that $F(x)$ gives any vector in the span of $v$: Let $F(x) = (u \cdot x)v = bv$ where $b$ is a scalar. Then $F(ax/b) = (u \cdot ax/b) v = (a/b)bv = av$. Thus, the range of $F$ is the span of $v$.

(c) The $i$th column in the matrix of $F$ with respect to the standard ordered basis is $F(\epsilon_i) = (u \cdot \epsilon_i)v = u_iv$. Thus, the matrix of $F$ is $v^tu$.